# Switching 'active' class on li item not working when 'href' value set to any link

Tags: html, jquery

I created a Navigation menu for my website which has some styles on active page link, my code works fine until I add any redirecting link to "href" attribute of the 'a' tag, and when I set "href" value to '#' everything works fine.

Below is my HTML,CSS and JS code for the navigation menu.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.navbar ul li').on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');

  })
})
```

```css
.navbar {
      padding: 0;
    }
  
    .navbar ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      list-style: none;
      align-items: center;
    }
  
    .navbar li {
      position: relative;
    }
  
    .navbar a,
    .navbar a:focus {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding: 10px 0 10px 30px;
      font-family: Georgia, serif;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: 400;
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      white-space: nowrap;
      transition: 0.3s;
      text-decoration:none;
    }
  
    .navbar a i,
    .navbar a:focus i {
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 0;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
  
    .navbar a:hover,
    .navbar .active>a,
    .navbar .active:focus,
    .navbar li:hover>a {
      color: green;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.php" >Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="workflow.php">Work flow</a>
          <li><a href="illustration.php">Illustration</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav><!-- .navbar -->
```

Comment: You need to cancel the click event.  You're clicking on the `a`, which is propagating up to your event handler, but still firing the default action: navigate to the href.  Add `return false;` to the end of your click handler.

Comment: If there's a URL in the `href`, then clicking on it will go to that page.

Comment: I'm guessing (having seen similar questions about 200times now) that you *do* want to navigate to (eg) about.php and then have the About tab highlighted.  That's a very different question and there are numerous solutions on SO already.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for reply, I read multiple quetion with same issue tried all the solutions but nothing worked so far, thats why I asked this question.
Also when adding return false; then the links stops redirecting to the desired page.

Comment: *then the links stops redirecting to the desired page* - yes, obviously, hence my comment about what you *probably* want (but didn't ask).    You have two pages - if you change the tab on the first one, it won't be changed on the second one.  Your second page needs to check its url to determine if it should be selected.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for the hint, I got it fixed by adding php if else condition to check the page name and specified a page variable on each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue my self, below is the code for same:

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="<?php if ($page=='home') {echo "active";} ?>"><a href="index.php" >Home</a></li>
      <li class="<?php if ($page=='workflow') {echo "active";} ?>"><a href="workflow.php">Work flow</a>
      <li class="<?php if ($page=='illustration') {echo "active";} ?>"><a href="illustration.php">Illustration</a></li>
      <li class="<?php if ($page=='about') {echo "active";} ?>"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
      <li class="<?php if ($page=='contact') {echo "active";} ?>"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav><!-- .navbar -->
```

This is the Html I modified added If else condition in class attribute.
And also added below line on each page on which the links are being redirected.

```
<?php 
    $page = 'home';
?>
```

Comment: You accept your own answer - this looks like a nice solution.